# Is there a way to tell if an end user will be able to handle <a href=“mailto:###”> links?

Tags: javascript, cross-browser, mailto

I'm trying to adapt to the situation in which a user has no email client installed (like in my case: i use opera's internal mail client, so if i click a mailto: link i internet explorer i won't get anything.))

Comment: No. They either have configured their browser to open their mail client (IE configured to open Opera Mail in your case), or they don’t.

Comment: so how can i handle the latter case?

Comment: ... the best way in my opinion is to modify the link after clicked once to href to a php mailer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment it is not possible. The closest thing to an answer I ended up with this:

```
<a id="mail-link" href="mailto:the@email.it" onclick="if (this.hasAttribute('data-clickedonce')) {this.setAttribute('href','mailform.php?to=the@email.it');} this.setAttribute('data-clickedonce','yes');">Send a Mail</a>
```

The script embedded in the a tag changes the href on the second press.
The theory is: if the user has no way to handle the mail protocol, nothing happens and he/she will certainly try to click the link another time.